# Java: What is the right way to convert String into a valid amount of money(BigDecimal)

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have to convert an incoming String field into a BigDecimal field that would represent a valid amount of money, for example:

```
String amount = "1000";

BigDecimal valid_amount = convert(amount);

print(valid_amount.toString())//1000.00
```

What is the right API to use convert a String into a valid amount of money in Java (eg: apache commons library)?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about the `BigDecimal(String)` constructor?

```
String amount = "1000";
BigDecimal validAmount = new BigDecimal(amount);
System.out.println(validAmount); // prints: 1000
```

If you want to format the output differently, use the `Formatter` class.

Answer (score 6):

Did you mean to achieve the following:?

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
System.out.println(nf.format(new BigDecimal("1000")));
```

Output

```
$1,000.00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print decimal with, use setScale method

```
String amount = "1000";
BigDecimal validAmount = new 
BigDecimal(amount).setScale(2,RoundingMode.CEILING);
System.out.println(validAmount); // prints: 1000.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `new BigDecimal(strValue)`.

Will save you enormous pain and suffering resulting from [The Evil BigDecimal Constructor](http://rayfd.wordpress.com/2007/04/26/the-evil-bigdecimal-constructor/)

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Joda-Money](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/) library for dealing with money values.  But, according to the web site, "the current development release intended for feedback rather than production use."